# When to use Immutable.js Set over List for unique values

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Using Immutable.js assuming each element must be unique is there any advantage or purpose to use 'List' over 'Set'? Or to put it another way, if the elements must unique, should I always be using 'Set'? Or is there some situation where I would be better off using 'List'?

Ive realized nearly all my array based data is usually unique, but I've been primarily using 'List' in the past.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you want a Set. You don't need any order either, do you?

Comment: No order doesn't matter

Comment: Then you definitely should use a `Set`.